# SVG / CSS Animation with animation-delay breaking

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have a relatively simple SVG/CSS animation which scales in three paths one after another on a loop.

There is a CSS `animation-delay` set on each path.  However, only the first path (with the `.one` class and an `animation-delay: 0ms`) is animated -  the other two, with `animation-delay: 600ms` and `animation-delay: 1200ms` are not visible.

Oddly, when inspecting with Google Chrome and selecting the second (`.two`) and third (`.three`) paths in the Elements tab, they appear to be present and scaling but are just not visible!

Removing the delay completely (or setting to `0ms` shows all three scaling, but obviously I need the delay to be present and for them to animate in one after another.

Below is a simple HTML document illustrating the problem. For reference, I have tried using browser vendor prefixes too - this has not worked and I have omitted these for brevity.

```html
<html>

<style>

  .spinner-cell {
animation: fio 4000ms ease-out infinite;
animation-delay: 3600ms;
transform: scale(0);
  }

.one {
  animation-delay: 0ms;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.two {
  animation-delay: 600ms;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.three {
  animation-delay: 1200ms;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

  @keyframes fio {
0% {
  transform: scale(0.1);
}

5% {
  transform: scale(1);
}

50% {
  transform: scale(0.99);
}

60% {
  transform: scale(0);
}
  }
</style>

<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150" >
    <g>
      <path
        class="spinner-cell one"
        fill="#ffa000"
        d="M124.374 68.244H92.667c-2.381 0-4.581-1.271-5.771-3.332L71.043 37.454c-1.19-2.063-1.19-4.603 0-6.664L86.896 3.332C88.086 1.271 90.287 0 92.667 0h31.706c2.381 0 4.581 1.27 5.771 3.332l15.854 27.458c1.19 2.062 1.19 4.602 0 6.664l-15.854 27.458c-1.19 2.062-3.391 3.332-5.77 3.332zM96.515 54.916h24.012l12.006-20.794-12.006-20.793H96.515L84.509 34.122l12.006 20.794z"
      />
    </g>
    <g>
      <path
        class="spinner-cell two"
        fill="#ffa000"
        d="M54.223 108.859H22.516c-2.381 0-4.581-1.271-5.771-3.332L.893 78.068c-1.19-2.062-1.19-4.602 0-6.664l15.853-27.458c1.19-2.062 3.39-3.332 5.771-3.332h31.707c2.381 0 4.581 1.271 5.771 3.332l15.854 27.458c1.189 2.063 1.189 4.603 0 6.664l-15.854 27.459c-1.192 2.063-3.391 3.332-5.772 3.332zm-27.86-13.328h24.012l12.006-20.794-12.006-20.795H26.363L14.357 74.737l12.006 20.794z"
      />
    </g>
    <g>
      <path
        class="spinner-cell three"
        fill="#ffa000"
        d="M124.374 147.99H92.667c-2.381 0-4.581-1.271-5.771-3.331L71.043 117.2c-1.19-2.063-1.19-4.603 0-6.664l15.853-27.458c1.19-2.063 3.391-3.332 5.771-3.332h31.706c2.381 0 4.581 1.271 5.771 3.332l15.854 27.458c1.19 2.063 1.19 4.603 0 6.664l-15.854 27.459c-1.19 2.062-3.391 3.331-5.77 3.331zm-27.859-13.327h24.012l12.006-20.795-12.006-20.795H96.515l-12.006 20.795 12.006 20.795z"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems fine in Firefox. If you've found a Chrome bug, look for it in Chrome's bugtracker and report it if it's not there already.

Comment: Doesn't work in Edge either so perhaps a problem specific to Chromium.

Comment: You want to be here then: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/